# Getting information about many users using Spotify's API

Tags: api, web-scraping, spotify

I've looked briefly through Spotify's API documentation to try and see what exactly can be done with the API. I'm trying to do some data analysis on Spotify data, specifically on user listens / user playlists. However, as far as I can tell, the only way to uncover that information is through OAuth, and each user whose play information I desire would need to explicitly grant permission to my app to use their information. Since I am not building a user-facing app and am interested in doing mass analysis on many users at once, I don't think this would work for my purposes.

My question - is there any way to return multiple users' listening habits through a script that pulls data from Spotify using its API? Or is that possible strictly by way of an application that one user at a time gives authentication to when they load an app that uses this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to return multiple users' listening habits through a script that pulls data from Spotify using its API?

Spotify doesn't expose users' listening habits unless they authorized the app requesting it (I think this is what you meant when you said "through OAuth"). There's pretty big privacy reasons for not exposing users' data to the world.